# Proper punctuation

Tags: conjunctions

Please consider the following sentence.

> *A* has a unique association with *B* beyond its shared variance with *C* and *D*.

My question is whether *and* is joining *B* and *D*, or it is joining *C* and *D*. I mean to ask if *A* has a unique association with *B* and *D*, or *A* has shared variance with *C* and *D*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the usage of *its* in your example sentence. The syntax suggests that *its* is referring to A. This means that A is sharing the variance with *both* C and D.